# What is a transport order in supply chain management?

Tags: terminology, supply-chain

I arrived at this site as a result of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382954/looking-for-a-supply-chain-site-or-tag).

Last week, two colleagues were having a discussion about the term "Transport Order" in supply chain management. (Is it a recursive definition or can it only consist of different Vehicle Orders or other sub-orders, are there limitations about what a Transport Order NOT can be, ...?)

I wonder if there is an official definition for terms like "Transport Order", "Vehicle Order", "Robot Order", ...

Comment: Nobody knows an official glossary for supply chain "science"?

Comment: https://cscmp.org/CSCMP/Educate/SCM_Definitions_and_Glossary_of_Terms.aspx is your best resource.

Comment: @RalphAsher: unfortunately, neither the terms "transportorder" or "transport order" (with double-quotes for mentioning it's one word) are known by that site.

Answer (score 3):

According to a colleague in supply chain management (who is not 100% confident in his answer), the phrase "transport order" frequently (usually?) means an order to move stock from one facility to another within the same company (meaning there is no purchase or sale involved).

Comment: I have never heard the term transport order.  A transfer order is just that, an order to move between facilities

Comment: This is indeed what it means, but I'm looking for limitations of that term: can a transportorder contain other transportorders or not, how to you call a collection of transportorders, what with the suborders (vehicleorders, robotorders, ...)?

Comment: Can you provide some context for this inquiry?