# What is the official terminology concerning different types of racks?

Tags: terminology, supply-chain

Thanks to [a previous question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9137), I know about [this PDF file, containing a lot of terms concerning supply chain management](https://cscmp.org/CSCMP/Educate/SCM_Definitions_and_Glossary_of_Terms.aspx).

This list is quite elaborated, but I'm now more specifically looking for different terms of racks. The list contains "Flow rack", "Cantilever rack" and the extremely general term "Pallet rack", but I'm interested in different types of racks, e.g. based on the amount of entries and exits for entering and getting items to and from the rack, or even more terms.

Is there a list of supply chain terms around storage locations, like racks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is categorized under ***warehouse space and its related handling system optimization***. For example, the first term `Flow rack` referred to the storage location near to production line(s) to feed the row/WIP materials into the line(s) based on the FIFO strategy and also with the aid of gravity to move the small pallets on the rack. Usually feeding from the back and consuming in front.

[image]

There are already many useful resources to study around this topic. One of the best is *[WAREHOUSE & DISTRIBUTION SCIENCE](https://www.warehouse-science.com/book/editions/wh-sci-0.98.1.pdf)* by Georgia Institute of Technology. Also, others would be [this](https://rackingandshelving.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/warehouseoperationshandout2.pdf) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/applications/jd-edwards/supply-chain-manufacturing/9.2/eoawm/defining-warehouse-specifications.html) links. Indeed, You could still find many related topics in the supply chain handbooks as well as warehouse service companies' technical materials.

Answer (score 1):

For general Supply Chain terms you can refer to manual from [APICS](http://www.apics.org/docs/default-source/certification/cpim-ecm-5-0-final-with-covers.pdf?sfvrsn=4) (they also provide a dictionary & an updated manual at a price).
For general racking systems [AR- Racking](https://www.ar-racking.com/en/news-and-blog/storage-solutions/storage-racking-solutions/types-of-industrial-racking-for-the-warehouse-classification-and-characteristics) storage solutions kind of most comprehensive list of different racks, their classifications and use.
For general warehouse related terms and operations, this [link](https://www.apexwarehousesystems.com/coming-to-terms-with-the-material-handling-word-soup/) provides a glossary.